# Node.js best practice for require

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am creating an Express application and using Mongoose to save data.

I created a User model (username&password). It needs to be able to be saved. So I use `require('mongoose')` in Models/user-model.js. In the route for User I want to be able to get all the users or just find some. So I need to `require('mongoose')` there as well. Also in the main js file (app.js) I create a connection to the database so there is a `require('mongoose')` there as well.

It all works well, but is it the best way to require mongoose in all of these files? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I just require as needed like you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, "*best*" is hard to say for certain. But, what you're doing is a common-enough practice and should be fine in most cases.

The 1st time `mongoose` is required, it'll be [cached for subsequent requires](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching):

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to `require('foo')` will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.
>
> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be executed multiple times. [...]

Comment: I have also seen people just simply throw the db object directly under the req object so that in any middle-ware you can simply get to it w/ req.db. Not sure if this is _best_ practice but it's common.

Answer (score 0):

With module caching in mind...do you think that is a good idea to create a global APP object and store things like models and libraries in the bootstrap and then just pass that object to other modules or just require the module dependencies when it needed no matter if our modules have a lot of require() sentences ?